# Django: no such table: django_session when using with postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm building a blog with Django and I have configured my server with nginx and uwsgi. Everything works fine on the test server from manage.py but when I try to access it externally I get

```
OperationalError at /admin/
no such table: django_session
```

when I try to login to the admin console. Before this I was getting a similiar error but with `auth_user` instead of `django_session`. I have configured the server using postgres and when I log in using the blogs user to the database all the tables appear to be there. I noticed this line on the error page `/srv/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py` which I thought to be strange given that the database is in postgres. I tried running syncdb but it returned that there were unmigrated changes and performing makemigrations and migrate didn't fix the problem.

Comment: do you have `site` in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: Well my app is called mainblog not site but it is in there yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I managed to solve the problem by deleting the existing database and migrating again.